# How to implement a where clause in Datastore on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

The purpose of this API is to list all Servers owned by a certain `User` E-mail Address.

If I remove the filter, then the method returns all Servers (as expected). The problem, is that I need to filter by a specific E-mail Address, which only ever returns a result such as:

```
{
 "kind": "serverApi#resources",
 "etag": "\"q4aBTdWQBYSnhbijLrKGtcu63OU/cXL3GSvQ29gE3tK-4VKxQrWjAt0\""
}
```

I am expecting a result similar to:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "1",
   "hostname": "aaa",
   "ip": "192.168.1.2",
   "mac": "00:00:00:00:00:00",
   "user": "a@b.c",
   "domain": "HOME",
   "kind": "serverApi#resourcesItem"
  },
  {
   "id": "2",
   "hostname": "bbb",
   "ip": "192.168.1.1",
   "mac": "00:00:00:00:00:00",
   "user": "a@b.c",
   "domain": "HOME",
   "kind": "serverApi#resourcesItem"
  },
  {
   "id": "3",
   "hostname": "ccc",
   "ip": "192.168.1.3",
   "mac": "00:00:00:00:00:00",
   "user": "a@b.c",
   "domain": "HOME",
   "kind": "serverApi#resourcesItem"
  },
  {
   "id": "4",
   "hostname": "ddd",
   "ip": "192.168.1.4",
   "mac": "00:00:00:00:00:00",
   "user": "a@b.c",
   "domain": "HOME",
   "kind": "serverApi#resourcesItem"
  }
 ],
 "kind": "serverApi#resources",
 "etag": "\"q4aBTdWQBYSnhbijLrKGtcu63OU/cXL3GSvQ29gE3tK-4VKxQrWjAt0\""
}
```

The code I am using on my Endpoint.

```
public CollectionResponse<Server> listServerByUser(User user) throws OAuthRequestException {
    List<Server> records = new ArrayList<Server>();

    Query<Server> query = ofy().load().type(Server.class).filter("mUser", user.getEmail());
    QueryResultIterator<Server> iterator = query.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        records.add(iterator.next());
    }

    return CollectionResponse.<Server>builder().setItems(records).build();
}
```

Columns as shown in the `Datastore Viewer` on the AppEngine Dashboard:

> `ID/Name` `mDomain`   `mHostname` `mIp`   `mMac`  `mUser`

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is: you don't get all the records that you expect, or the record is returned with a different data that you expect. Please, clarify.

Comment: I expect to receive 4 results. The e-mail addresses match.

Comment: I see you are actually using Objectify, and the string format you are using is correct [1] (no operator means equals). Perhaps you are filtering on the wrong property (is it 'user' instead if 'mUser'?) or user.getEmail() isn't returning what you think it is? [1] http://docs.objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/git/apidocs/com/googlecode/objectify/cmd/Query.html#filter(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index the properties where you are filtering or ordering on.

Since you're using Objectify, you need to edit the `User` class with the proper `@Index` annotation

Here is the full guide to the indexing process

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Queries

After you add the annotation, the indexing process is not retroactive.
You need to put again all entities the property of each entity (a simple get+put with Objectify is enough)

Comment: This looks extremely promising. I had not seen that annotation when I checked this morning. I will check that again later today. The documentation link provided is also very descriptive. The sentence "Queries only return values in an index. If an entity field is not indexed, queries on that field will return no results." would have saved me a lot of time, had I found that sooner!

Answer (score 1):

If mUser property is not indexed, you are not going to find any results when you use it in a filter.

Comment: This is most likely my problem. How can I add an Index to a column? I am using Android Studio, if that helps. I located this document, would this be correct? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig

Comment: You don't need to add index definitions for single properties. You need to annotate the properties that you want to index.